# Trying to find sample standard deviation of a proportion

Tags: standard-error, proportion

The data set is 32% of n:2000
CI: 95

I did
$x=\pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{0.32*0.68}{2000}}$
and

$CI=0.32\pm 1.96 * \frac{0.466}{\sqrt{2000}}$

to find the confidence interval

My numbers came out pm 0.34, 0.29

Answer (score 1):

The interval you are using is called the [Wald interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Normal_approximation_interval_or_Wald_interval), and it is not a particularly good method for estimating a proportion in binary data.  A better approach is to use the [Wilson score interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Wilson_score_interval), specifically designed for estimating a proportion in binary data.  (The two methods give similar answer in this case because you have a large sample size, but in general, the Wilson score interval is far superior.)  The properties of the latter interval are discussed in detail in [O'Neill (2021)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.12464).

It is simple to implement the confidence interval for a proportion using the `CONF.prop` function in the [`stat.extend` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=stat.extend) (in the statistical computing language `R`).  Here is how to do it for the data you have:

```
library(stat.extend)
CONF.prop(alpha = 0.05, n = 2000, sample.prop = 0.32)

        Confidence Interval (CI) 
 
95.00% CI for proportion parameter for infinite population 
Interval uses 2000 binary data points with sample proportion = 0.3200 

[0.299917915975882, 0.340772221045369]
```

Comment: I have a strong preference to `binom::binom.confint(x=0.32*2000, n=2000)` as it shows 11 different CIs types all together. It really emphasises when someone should be worried and when someone should just keep moving. (I personally prefer the Agresti-Cull as it is simple to use and still "mostly fine" in the edges, but really I have found that most of the time the differences are immaterial....)

Comment: Fair enough.  I prefer the Wilson score anyway.  Also the ```CONF.prop``` function allows inference for a finite population size and also allows inference for the unsampled proportion, which ```binom.confint``` doesn't do.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that! (+1).

Comment: Full disclosure: I programmed the ```stat.extend``` package, so take my own positive evaluation of its functions with a grain of salt - they are useful *to me*.

Comment: OOoooohhhh.... (+1) (No worries, I wouldn't accuse you for R nepotism!)